# How to set APT to use squid-deb-proxy without squid-deb-proxy-client?

Tags: apt, proxy, squid-deb-proxy

In my network I have Squid proxy server for caching deb-archives. It is installed as `squid-deb-proxy` package.

I know that special package `squid-deb-proxy-client` exists in the repositories.
But it requires `avahi-utils` as a dependency.

How can I set APT on client machines to use `squid-deb-proxy` without `squid-deb-proxy-client`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add one line to the APT configuration file `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or to custom file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99proxy`:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://[[user][:pass]@]host[:port]";
```

where

- `[[user]:[pass]@]` are credentials (`user` is username, `pass` is password);
- `host` is hostname of proxy server or its IP;
- `[:port]` is a port (`8000` in case of `squid-deb-proxy`).

Example: `http://192.168.12.34:8000` for anonymous proxy -

```
echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy "http://192.168.12.34:8000";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99proxy
```

Removal:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99proxy
# or 
mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99proxy ~/
```

See the *The Acquire group* of [man 5 apt.conf](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/apt.conf.5.html).

Note: this line may be added during installation via netboot installer if you have set proxy-server in it.